# PLSQL Select more than one values and put it into more than one variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

is it possible to write a PLSQL Select Into Statement for many values?

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT X,Y,Z INTO v1,v2,v3 FROM.....
```

If so, can anyone show me an example?

Comment: [The syntax is correct](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS207) What happened when you tried?

Comment: What you have written is correct, all you have to do is declare the variables in the DECLARE block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `INTO` clause for more than 1 variables. I have created a sample block for you.

```
declare 
x int;
y int;
z int;
begin
select 1,2,3 into x,y,z from dual;
 dbms_output.Put_line('x='||x||',y='||y||',z='||z);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking here about an INSERT INTO statement, but another option I would like to show here is the use of a cursor.

```
DECLARE
        -- Fetch the first 5 entries of the table.
        CURSOR cTableA IS
               SELECT  ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
               FROM    TableA
               WHERE   ROWNUM <= 5;

        rTableA cTableA%ROWTYPE; --Not realy needed this time, but some think it is neat.
BEGIN
        FOR rTableA IN cTableA LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ColumnA: ' || rTableA.ColumnA);
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ColumnB: ' || rTableA.ColumnB);
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ColumnB: ' || rTableA.ColumnC);
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```